# Failed to resolve: com.firebase-client-android:2.4.0

Tags: firebase

I have tried with, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3
Bt nothing works.

```
dependencies {
Classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:1.3.0'
  }
```

Comment: can you post your full stack trace of the error

Comment: @KiranB : Did you try to debug the doInBackground().

Comment: I have shown the full stack trace error@peeyush pathak

Comment: no.I didnt try debugging it.@Pawan

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why my previous answer was deleted.

Add the below line to your `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

If already added then let know, will think of another solution.

Comment: Yes i have added it..but getting the same problem

Comment: @KiranB Try cleaning the project and re-building it once. Also confirm if the above line is added to your app's build.gradle file not the project's build.gradle file.
There are 2 files in the project.

Comment: Yes..I have added it apps build.gradle file. After cleaning and rebuilding, it's showing errors given below.  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.

Comment: @KiranB Check if you have downloaded/updated 'Android Support Repository' from SDK manager?