# Rendering problems in the layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am seeing these messages

> Rendering problems The following classes could not be found android.support.design.widget.appbarlayout(Fix build path, Create class) android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout(Fix build path,Create class)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems ... Instead of 20 , select it to 23

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering problems in Android studio in the layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342527/rendering-problems-in-android-studio-in-the-layouts)

Comment: Pleases edit your previous questions. Do **not** repost

Comment: check out here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line to you `build.gradle` file?

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change in  build.gradle

from :

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
 }
```

to :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

or what ever is the number just put 0.0 at the end

Comment: no but it's solution for his problem
he can do 23+'

Comment: yup but sometimes fix render problems ;)

Comment: The error sounds like the classes aren't on the class path. The fact that changing a version number of a library may help is because those classes actually exist in that version